# Meaning of "no more right"

Tags: phrases

> Man has no more right to say an uncivil thing than to act one

According to me the meaning of this phrase is:

> Man has equal right to say an uncivil thing and to act an uncivil thing.

Am I right?

Comment: [buzzer for:] than to act one. to act an uncivil thing is not really English....

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially correct. However, "equal right" leaves out some of the implication of the sentence - a more complete rephrasing would be something like

> Saying an uncivil thing is *no better than* doing an uncivil thing.

The original phrase uses "no more" to emphasize not simply that the actions are equal, but that they are equal *in spite of* what others might think (that saying something uncivil is a lesser offence). It's calling attention to the fact that someone *might* think they have more right to the former, but that the writer does not agree.

Comment: I don't agree that the original sentence is saying that you have zero right: it might imply that, but it does not say it.

Comment: @ColinFine After some consideration I changed my answer - I was over-simplifying. Thanks for the feedback.